# Как решить эту небольшую задачку на python?

Tags: python, циклы, случайные-числа

В списке целых, заполненном случайными числами вычислить произведение элементов с индексами кратными 3
Вот попытка но она не верная(только недавно начал изучать Пайтон)))

```
from random import random
N = 10
arr = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
    arr[i] = int(random() * 10)
print(arr)
s = 0
for i in range(N):
    if arr[i] % 2 != 0:
        s += arr[i]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from random import random
N = 10
arr = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
    arr[i] = int(random() * 10)
print(arr)

s = 1
for i in range(0, N, 3):
    s *= arr[i]
print(s)
```

Comment: почему она считает так
[6, 4, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 7, 0, 9]
648
а должно быть 108?
то есть 3 * 4 * 9 
индекс 3 * 6 * 9

Comment: @alex0711 шестерку в нулевом индексе не считаете? вам же нужно произведение "элементов с индексами кратными 3"? 0 кратен 3 ))

Comment: ааа понял спасибо)))